# A contradiction regarding flux conservation

Tags: circuit-analysis, magnetics, flux

Consider a simple circuit

[image: Flux]

Initially switch S was opened till steady state is reached and then it was closed. My understanding regarding inductors is that you can't have a SUDDEN change in current flowing through an inductor otherwise it would result in VERY LARGE (infinite) potential difference across it. (as the magnitude of time derivative of current will shoot to infinity!).

After switch S is closed, we're asked to find the current across inductor 1. 
My teacher told me to apply flux conservation to find the current just after the switch S is closed. Flux conservation would say that current is suddenly changed as soon as switch is closed.

But how is it possible to have a SUDDEN change in current flowing across inductor 1, moreover I still don't understand exactly WHY flux is conserved.

Is my understanding regarding inductors wrong?

1. How to resolve this contradiction?
2. Why Flux is conserved?

EDIT: The flux conservation says that current will suddenly change because-
[image]

Clearly initial current (when switch S is opened and steady state is reached) isifferent from final (after switch S is closed).

Comment: Why do you say that flux conservation means that the current would change suddenly?

Comment: Sorry, but your added equations don't make any sense. In a dc circuit an inductor acts like a short circuit, a resistance of zero ohms, and the inductance value is irrelevant. In a dc situation the current is not affected the slightest bit by the value of the inductors.

Comment: Whoever made this question was probably assuming that when you close the switch, it's the same as removing L2 from the circuit also (e.g, using a SPDT switch instead of using a SPST). Definitely ask your instructor. It may be worthwhile to solve the alternate problem, so you have a solution ready depending on what they say.

Answer (score 3):

Your contradiction is based on your false model of the physics:

In steady state, the voltage across L1 and L2 is zero, each, simply because a inductor has zero effective resistance to DC.

So, closing the switch ironically won't do anything in this idealized model: with zero voltage across the switch, there's no reason for current to flow through the switch.

So, closing the switch changes nothing in this idealized model.

---

One could, however, just as well say: well, if I put two perfect conductors (the closed switch and L2 for DC) in parallel, then the current would be split half-and-half; but that's really just a fallacy, because you simply can't find a reason that this should be happening. The current-divider rules you know only apply to cases where there's some impedance in both branches; that's not the case here, and the math becomes ill-defined.

---

What will happen with this circuit in reality is that of course, an inductor has ohmic resistance, and so the voltage across L2 isn't *actually* zero. A current will hence flow through the switch once closed, in the opposite direction as the current through L2. That current will need to come from "somewhere". So, yes, the current through L2 will change in reality, but certainly not SUDDENly, to put it in your words. See Scott's answer for a discussion of the differential equation you'd need to solve.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. @Marcus Miller Consider the instant when switch is closed. The current changes instantaneouly, thereby the derivative of current at that instant is infinite making the potential across inductor infinite.

Comment: @ShivanshJ No. At dc the voltage across the inductor **must be** zero. Therefore, closing the switch **does not** change the voltage across the inductor. Therefore, closing the switch **does not** change the current through the inductor.

Comment: @Marcus Miller You are right that before closing that switch the potential across inductor is zero,but I'm not concerned with that. I'm more worried about the potential across inductor AT the instant of closing the switch.

Comment: @ShivanshJ Sure, but it's still zero assuming ideal components.

Comment: @ShivanshJ it doesn't change, as I wrote, and as Elliot and Hearth both confirmed for you. The potential before, while and after changing is simply 0.

Comment: @Marcus Miller Okay so this means that the solution is posted in above question which involves flux conservation is wrong?

Comment: I don't understand where your first equation even comes from, so I guess that yes, it's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my confusion, but still a small doubt left. There's another similar question like mine (I did not find answers on them satisfying that's why I asked), but on that question people claimed that magnetic flux must be conserved. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/419843/magnetic-flux-conservation?r=SearchResults

Comment: Then you didn't understand anything: the flux is conserved. There isn't a sudden change in current. There can't be. end of story.

Comment: @ShivanshJ This is not the same situation; in that question, a connection is broken and a new connection is made. In this one, you're only adding a connection.

Comment: I'm very much confused can you please elaborate more?

Comment: In that question too, isn't current across the inductors changing suddenly?

Comment: @Marcus Muller I think that's rude, you don't know how much I've tried to understand this whole flux thing! Tons of books. It's just a small confusion and it would be better if you please elaborate more on your point.

Comment: @ShivanshJ Don't ask a new question in the comments. If you have another question, make it another question.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson Pardon me if I went wrong somewhere.

Comment: @ShivanshJ you've had multiple people now explain to you that and why the current doesn't change suddenly. I don't really know how to help you if you can't drop the assumption that the current changes.

Comment: @Marcus Muller No hard feelings and sorry if you think that I was rude. I think (maybe wrongly) you're saying that I should drop out the assumption and accept the idea that current is changing but not in a SUDDEN manner? (As you mentioned in your answer, the last point). Are you also saying that my model is oversimplified?

Comment: @ShivanshJ I see where your confusion comes from. The question you're linking as a reference shows an un-physical situation; in reality, the inductor's current won't change instantaneously, but due to effects that are not considered in idealized models. In reality, in that question, the switch would form an electric arc when it was opened.

Comment: @Hearth Thank you very much "In reality, the inductor's current won't change simultaneously.." helped a LOT! But lastly as I have asked in this question (which nobody has explained) in idealized model we're conserving magnetic flux. Can you tell me why?

Comment: because it's an idealized model.

Answer (score 0):

\$ V= L \frac{di}{dt}\$, no two ways about it.

If \$\frac{di}{dt}\$ is infinite, so is the voltage across the inductor.

This is not a contradiction.  It is very hard to produce a truly infinite rate of change of current -- especially when the inductor varies from ideal with an effective series resistance.